# Splitting text into words in MySQL

Tags: mysql, text

Suppose I have a table `products` with

| product | description |
| --- | --- |
| apple | yummy green fruit |
| banana | nutritional yellow fruit |

Notice that the `description` column may contain texts of arbitrary length (LONGTEXT). Now I want to get the table `words` with all of the words from the column `description`:

| words |
| --- |
| yummy |
| green |
| fruit |
| nutritional |
| yellow |

All of the answers I have found on StackExchange refer to splitting a string into several columns, not rows. How do I approach this problem?

EDIT: `SELECT VERSION();` returns:

| VERSION() |
| --- |
| 8.0.27 |

Comment: Please run `SELECT VERSION();` and report the result.

Comment: Does some maximal amount of words per value exists? Or it is indefinite and may exceed any predefined value?

Comment: @Akina indefinite amount of words per value, the column "description" contains texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Edit :

> The description column may contain texts of arbitrary length
> (LONGTEXT)

The following query shall work for LONGTEXT.

```
INSERT INTO words
SELECT DISTINCT REGEXP_REPLACE(TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(description, ' ', numbers.n), ' ', -1)), '[^[:alnum:]]', '') AS word
FROM
  (SELECT @row := @row + 1 AS n FROM (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) t1,
  (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) t2,
  (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5) t3,
  (SELECT @row:=0) t4) numbers
  INNER JOIN products
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(description) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(description, ' ', '')) >= numbers.n - 1;
```

Here is the [DBFIDDLE Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/efdRXBpD).

The above code shall also remove any comma, quotes, hyphen, semicolon and other special characters before inserting individual words to a table.

If you are fine with duplicate entries (words) in a table; then you remove the distinct clause at start of query.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    product VARCHAR(255),
    description LONGTEXT
    );

INSERT INTO products (product, description) VALUES 
('apple', 'yummy green fruit'),
('banana', 'nutritional yellow fruit');
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT word
FROM products
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
    CONCAT('["', REPLACE(description, ' ', '","'), '"]'),
    '$[*]' COLUMNS (
        word VARCHAR(255) PATH '$'
        )
    ) jsontable
```

| word |
| --- |
| yummy |
| green |
| fruit |
| nutritional |
| yellow |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/87n7t7ml)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. 
MySQL returns: ERROR 3141 (22032): Invalid JSON text in argument 1 to function json_table: "Invalid encoding in string." at position XX. 
MariaDB returns: ERROR 4036 (HY000): Character disallowed in JSON in argument 1 to function 'JSON_TABLE' at position XX.

Comment: @JantjeGöhre Adjust charset. `CONVERT()`..